# MediaPlayer working on emulator, but not on device

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, emulation

I am working on a radio app for Android and I've found a strange issue. That's a part of the code:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
```

The program works well on the emulator (2.2, 2.3), but when I try on my two devices (both Android 2.2) there is no audio. I've tried a lot of workarounds, but it seems so strange that Audio works on emulator, but not on devices.

PS: I've set Internet permissions

All the listiners are up (OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener, OnInfoListener, OnPreparedListener) On emulator I listen the music, but it gives error in logcat: [emulator log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/854176/emulatorLOGCAT.txt)

This is the error showed in logcat (on device):

```
E/OMXPlayer(  953): Creating new NVOMXPlayer: 0x9c1a8
E/OMXPlayer(  953): onFirstRef ++
E/OMXPlayer(  953): onFirstRef --
E/OMXPlayer(  953): setdatasource ++
E/OMXPlayer(  953): 0x9c1a8 setDataSource url=http://XXXXXX:8000
E/OMXPlayer(  953): render thread(10972) started: 0x9c1a8
E/OMXPlayer(  953): STATE_PREPARING - signal wait 0x9c1a8
E/OMXPlayer(  953): prepareAsync: 0x9c1a8
E/OMXPlayer(  953): STATE_PREPARING - signal rx'd 0x9c1a8
E/OMXPlayer(  953): prepare 0x9c1a8
E/OMXPlayer(  953): 0x9c1a8 Creating player for: http://XXXXX:8000
D/        (  961): NVRM_DAEMON(803): rt_exist=2, add client ref
D/        (  953): NvMMSetUserAgentString:: Len: 49: String: User-Agent: (NvMM Client v0.1; Linux;Android 2.2)
D/        (  953): connect cancelled
D/        (  953): connect cancelled
D/        (  953): connect cancelled
D/        (  953): connect cancelled
D/        (  953): connect cancelled
D/        (  953): connect cancelled
D/        (  953): connect cancelled
D/        (  953): Event_BlockError from 13SuperParser : Error code - 4
D/        (  953): Graph_EventHandler: ERROR for READER [0x80001005]
D/        (  953): Graph_EventHandler: ERROR for READER [0x80001005]
E/MediaPlayer(10958): error (1, 0)
E/        (10958): Prepare failed.: status=0x1
E/        (10958): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
E/        (10958):      at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
E/        (10958):      at app.relax.com.StreamingMediaPlayer.listen(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:64)
E/        (10958):      at app.relax.com.StreamingMediaPlayer.startListening(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:74)
E/        (10958):      at app.relax.com.StreamingMediaPlayer.access$0(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:70)
E/        (10958):      at app.relax.com.StreamingMediaPlayer$1.run(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:51)
E/        (10958):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
E/OMXPlayer(  953): prepare 0x9c1a8 exit with error
E/OMXPlayer(  953): Error in prepare
E/OMXPlayer(  953): Worker Thread Exit -
```

Comment: What returns "isPlaying()"? Is your stream playing or not? Make sure you set the volumn. You can also register a listener to check if there are warnings or errors "setOnInfoListener()".

Comment: on the devices it gives me a decoder error, in the emulator works. I really don't understand what's going on :|

Comment: @Copa have u got a solution? I really don't know what to do.

Comment: no one? :( I've done a lot of tests, but only works on emulator

Comment: i have the same problem. Have you been able to find the solution @Stefano ?

Answer (score 0):

What's the media type of the stream? Perhaps you're missing CODECs for that format on the production devices.

Honestly, the production devices tend have better CODECs than the emulators because the 2.x devices often have WMA as well as MP3 and MP4. But maybe that breaks something.

If it's playlist format (e.g. m3u), or a compound format (atom? rss?, or some other format with multiple stream URLs in multiple formats in an envelope), maybe the production devices pick a format that doesn't stream so well. e.g. they pick a WMA stream, but find out that it has DRM only when they start decoding.

Internet radio does often uses some kind of compound format. And they often put DRM on their WMA streams. That would be a good candidate, actually.

For what it's worth, 2.x streaming support is pretty weak. If you can crack the envelope and pick MP3 or MP4 instead of WMA you may do much better.

But the first question is: what's the format of the stream.

Also vaguely possible, I suppose: if your production devices are rooted, that disables decoding of DRM-protected files. Try it with an unrooted device?

Last possibility: 2.x devices use a variety of audio stacks. NVOMXPlayer doesn't look familiar. Are they Atrix devices?